# Ionic date and time

Tags: datetime, ionic-framework, datepicker

I am trying to implement a form in ionic and I am struggling with the date inputs. I set the upper range of the interval of dates allowed to be 2100 (comparing to the end of the current year,which is by default),but I want the following scenario to happen: when someone clicks to choose a date, I want the picker to start from the current date and to allow going up and down to choose a past of future date. At the moment,the picker starts at the upper end of the interval,2100, and it is difficult for someone to go down to 2016 or so,if they need dates close to the current day.

```
<ion-datetime max="2100-12-31" [(ngModel)]="formItem.input"></ion-datetime>
```

How can I achieve this? Thank you!

Comment: What is the value of `formItem.input` ? Normally, it should be init to that date.

Comment: It is undefined at the beginning. I am waiting for the user to pick the date and then formItem.input will hold that date.

Comment: And if you init to today (`new Date().toISOString()`)? Does it work ?

Comment: I tried so,but it also shows the date and doesn't allow me to clear it,if I don't need it. In other words,I want that the form opens with a form item such as: 

Date:

(that is, with no input displayed), and when I click on the picker, I want it to open with the current date as the first suggestion.